# UIImage from View with onAppear logic

Tags: swiftui, uikit, uiimage

I'm having a trouble to render a SwiftUI `View` to `UIImage` when I have any logic in View's `onAppear`.

For example, here we have a `SnapshotViewTest` that has a `Button` and should make a snapshot of `AGreatView` and show the `UIImage` result. `AGreatView` has only logic on `onAppear` –  to set the `width` of `Color.green` to 50 that I want to have on screen.

This is how it should look like:
[image: This is how it should look like]

This is how it looks like:
[image]

Here is the `SnapshotViewTest`:

```
struct SnapshotViewTest: View {
    @State var uiImage = UIImage()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Make a snapshot of a great view", action: {
                let view = AGreatView()
                
                uiImage = view.animation(nil).snapshot()
            })
            Image(uiImage: uiImage)
        }
    }
    
    struct AGreatView: View {
        @State var width = 0.0
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Text("Some text")
                Color.green.frame(width: width, height: 10) //works when I set "width" to any Double
            }.padding()
                .background(Color.red.opacity(0.1))
            .onAppear {
                DispatchQueue.main.async { //does not make any difference without
                    width = 50
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my View `snapshot func`:

```
extension View {
    func snapshot() -> UIImage {
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: self)
        let view = controller.view
        
        let targetSize = controller.view.intrinsicContentSize
        view?.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: targetSize)
                
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: targetSize)
        
        return renderer.image { _ in
            view?.drawHierarchy(in: controller.view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
        
    }
}
```

Thank you for any idea!

Answer (score 1):

you could try this, works for me:

```
Button("Make a snapshot of a great view", action: {
    let view = AGreatView()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        uiImage = view.snapshot()
    }
})
```

no need for `DispatchQueue` in `AGreatView` `onAppear`.

If that still does not work for you, try introducing a small delay, such as:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1)
```

Comment: Nice! I'm little perplexed as to why it works because the view renders in snapshot func but it works. However, I still need to get the DispatchQueue.main.async working (it's not needed in my example but I have an async call in my app and need to have some delay – to render view first, wait, and then make the photo). But my tries were unsuccessful.